# Ionic 2 import ionic-plugin-keyboard not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic2

I'm creating an Ionic (iOS) app and having **troubles importing the kayboard-plugin**.

It comes from here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

Why not the native keyboard plugin, because I want to use the `HideKeyboardAccessoryBar` functionality.

So I ran "cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard"
It was added perfectly inside the plugins folder.

Then in my `app.ts` file I cannot use the plugin.
I already used the following import statements:

```
import {Keyboard} from 'ionic-plugin-keyboard';
import {Keyboard} from 'ionic-plugin-keyboard/ionic-plugin-keyboard';
import {Keyboard} from '../plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/ionic-plugin-keyboard';
```

Then in my code I set

```
Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

But neither is working. always the same-like error

```
Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ionic-plugin-keyboard'.
```

Does anybody have any experience with this one?

Comment: Check out their keyboard documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/keyboard/

Comment: And read this bit to get an understanding of what Ionic Native is :) http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

Comment: @Will.Harris - But the native keyboard gives me "hideKeyboardAccessoryBar method has been removed temporarily."

Comment: After looking into it it sounds like that method has been temporarily removed because of issues with the IOS app store. The reason it says temporary is more than likely because once they have a fix they will implement it into the plugin. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/important-all-ionic-users-please-update-your-keyboard-plugin/46889/5

Comment: import { Keyboard } from 'ionic-native';

Comment: That works, but the KeyboardAccessoryBar is hidden by default, and I want it to be displayed. Since the function hideKeyboardAccessoryBar is temporarily removed...

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as a provider was added and it was ok
Check the [ionic forum](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10930)